# html, css Вписать 100% любое изображение в окне по ширине и высоте с пропорциями

Tags: javascript, html, css

Надо вписать изображение в окно сохраняя пропорции. Фотография может быть разных размеров 1000х200 или 333х1280.
В основном есть информация как вписать по ширине, но если попадается "высокая" фотография тогда она увеличивается в размере до своего максимума или до ширины.

Надо вписать 100% любое изображение в окно.

Comment: Чуть уточню. Надо чтобы в фотографии все были видны края, сохраняя пропорции. Например, в ваше фото должно вместиться в нижнее горизонтальное окноо.

Comment: Эффект должен быть такой, как если на компе открыть с помощью браузера фотографию.

Comment: Да. Спасибо. То что надо!